# Dokka generates docs with Java syntax instead of Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-dokka, dokka

I have a module with Kotlin code, and Dokka integrated.

When I'm running `./gradlew :core:clean :core:dokkaHtml` I'm getting following output with Java syntax, while this code is pure Kotlin:

[image]

Why and how to fix it?

Comment: the second example in the [readme](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka#applying-plugins) is how to add dokkaHtml to dokkaJavadoc.

Comment: @Alex.T lol, it's true, stupid me, the problem is that I've _added_ this dependency. Now I removed it and it works fine (and generates Kotlin docs). Could you please post your comment as an answer, so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

According to the dokka [readme](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka#applying-plugins):

> Applying plugins Dokka plugin creates Gradle configuration for each
> output format in the form of `dokka${format}Plugin`:

```
dependencies {
    dokkaHtmlPlugin("org.jetbrains.dokka:kotlin-as-java-plugin:1.6.10")
}
```

You can also create a custom Dokka task and add plugins directly inside:

```
val customDokkaTask by creating(DokkaTask::class) {
    dependencies {
        plugins("org.jetbrains.dokka:kotlin-as-java-plugin:1.6.10")
    }
}
```

> Please note that dokkaJavadoc task will properly document only single
> jvm source set
>
> To generate the documentation, use the appropriate dokka${format}
> Gradle task:

```
./gradlew dokkaHtml
```